# How to get rid of overriding limitations?

Tags: java

I have a problem with these two classes:

Creature:

```
public abstract class Creature extends Texturable
{
    public Creature(String ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    } // end Creature()

    protected void setMaximumHealthPoints(int maximumHealthPoints)
    {
        this.maximumHealthPoints = maximumHealthPoints;
    } // end setMaximumHealthPoints()

    protected void setMaximumSpeed(int maximumSpeed)
    {
        this.maximumSpeed = maximumSpeed;
    } // end setMaximumSpeed()

    ...

    protected String ID;
    protected int maximumHealthPoints;
    protected int maximumSpeed;
    ...
} // end Creature
```

Human:

```
public class Human extends Creature
{
    public Human(String ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        setMaximumHealthPoints(100);
        setMaximumSpeed(4);
    } // end Human()
} // end Human
```

What I want to do, is, as the above code says, set maximum health points to 100 and maximum speed to 4 but only for human creatures. :)

When I try to compile it I get the following error: constructor Creature in class Creature cannot be applied to given types. Arguments in Human and Creature constructors are identical. So, what's the problem?

I also tried this:

Human:

```
public class Human extends Creature
{
    protected int maximumHealthPoints = 100;
    protected int maximumSpeed = 4;
} // end Human
```

But with no success.

Now I get this error: "Field hides another field".

Is there anything I could do to make it work correctly?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

Comment: try calling `super(ID)` in human, you have no default constructor for creature only one that takes a param, or you can just add a default constructor, `public Creature(){}`

Comment: You'll want to follow Java naming conventions and make ID lower case id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is nothing to do with the maximum speed or health points bits - it's the constructor. Your `Creature` class only has one constructor, which takes a `String`. You're not specifying how to chain the the superclass constructor from Human, so the compiler is looking for an accessible parameterless constructor. A constructor *always* has to chain to either the superclass constructor or another constructor in the same class. If you don't specify anything to chain to with `super(...)` or `this(...)` then that's equivalent to:

```
super();
```

... which isn't valid in this case, as there's no such constructor to chain to.

You want:

```
// You should consider renaming ID to id, by the way...
public Human(String ID)
{
    super(ID);
    // Other stuff (but don't bother setting the ID field -
    // it's already been set by the Creature constructor)
}
```

I would also strongly advise you to make your fields private, and only access them from getter/setter methods declared in `Creature`.

Note that contrary to your title, there's no *overriding* going on here at all. Constructors aren't overridden - only methods are. Each class has its own set of constructor signatures; they aren't inherited at all - they just let you chain from the subclass to the superclass.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `Human` constructor to call the correct base class constructor like so:

```
public Human(String ID)
{
    super(ID);
    setMaximumHealthPoints(100);
    setMaximumSpeed(4);
}
```

Your code as it stands implicitly tries to call the parameterless constructor of `Creature`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

it is compulsory  to call the parent class's arguments constructor either implictely when you define a default non argument constructor , or explicitely when you define your custom constructor with arguments , as the suggested solutions show .

Comment: yep as long as the super constructor is called at the end